# Visual GUI Designer for Apache Pivot

Tags: java, gui-designer, apache-pivot

I learned about Apache Pivot's existence from the question [Java GUI frameworks. What to choose? Swing, SWT, AWT, SwingX, JGoodies, JavaFX, Apache Pivot?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7358775/9204) It seems like a good fit for my current project, as it involves letting users create their own GUI dynamically. However, I will also need to deliver a visual GUI designer for whatever technology I choose. Is there already such a designer for Pivot? Googling seems to suggest not, but I am asking in case I missed one.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but if a Visual GUI Designer is important, you might want to consider the [JavaFX SceneBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/scenebuilder/1/get_started/jsbpub-get_started.htm) if you have not done so already.

Comment: @jewelsea Two problems with JavaFX for me: 1) Linux support isn't done yet; 2) it looks like event handlers/controllers have to be written in Java and compiled (Pivot can embed handlers in scripting languages in BXML file). However, I might try using Groovy for this instead.

Comment: Apparently I was wrong on the second part, and you can have `<script>` tags in FXML. Good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been searching around a GUI designer for Pivot and it looks like developers just use XML editors when editing BXML. That being said, I did run across Geertjan's blog of an initial [GUI designer](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/pivot_integration_into_netbeans) for NetBeans called [NB-PIVOT](http://kenai.com/projects/nb-pivot). I don't know how active this project is. But it's a start.

Comment: Kenai is closed now -- did this exercise make it onto the Ark?

Comment: Wow.. Yep, seems to be gone. I don't know where to find it now. I don't do a lot of apache pivot work anymore so I haven't kept up with it.