# How do you create a RichTextBox in either C++ or Java

Tags: java, c++, richtextbox

Can someone give me a simple example of how to write text in a RichTextBox? I've looked online for some sample code without finding much help.

The only thing that I found was that I would have to declare a RichTextBox variable:

```
//Using C++
RichTextBox richbox = gcnew RichTextBox;
```

However, this doesn't work at all.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "this doesn't work"?  Are you seeing an error message?

Comment: I'm interested how it doesn't matter if it's Java or C++?

Comment: In Java you'll probably want to use a [JEditorPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html).

Comment: After I added that line, it said that it 'RichTextBox' was not a known identifier. Could this mean I need a header of some sort?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rich edit box controls are provided by many different frameworks. How they are implemented in either language will depend on the one you choose.

For C++ there is the ever popular windows specific Win32 API or MFC, or if you are diving into the .NET framework there is WinForms. There are also cross platform libraries like wxWidgets or Qt.

For Java, the JDK has AWT and Swing. There is also the Standard Widget Toolkit [and others](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7358775/416627).

Once you choose a language and a framework, try to create your application with the rich edit control. If you have trouble come back with your code and we can help you with more specific questions.