# Creating a simple gui in java for running a background process

Tags: java, unix, user-interface, solaris

Well, I had this question in mind for a long time.
Even though I have a complex requirement,i will keep it as simple as possible.

I have background process which takes two arguments which I use to execute from command line.
The first argumets can have three valid values and the secong argument can have two valid values.

I usually run that process on command line in solaris unix.and that process is completely coded in C++.

What I want now is I wish to create a simple gui in java for running the process in background.
I am complete new to the advanced concepts of java, and I am aware of some core java which I studied in my college days.

So,My question overe here how do I start creating a gui?
What all do I need to create a simple gui using java?
I am confident enough to learn gui programming in java as I am a c++ programmer.

Please give me some right directions to give some life to my thought and any some good materials available on the net would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by looking at;

- [Creating a GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html)
- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)
- [Concurrency in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)

I'd also become familiar with [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) (a simple [example](http://javaevangelist.blogspot.com.au/2011/12/java-tip-of-day-using-processbuilder-to.html)) and [Basic IO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)

MarvinLabs also makes some great points as well

Answer (score 1):

The Google search you'll want to use is "java swing tutorial". Swing is Java's GUI library.

You can also have a look at: [Java GUI frameworks. What to choose? Swing, SWT, AWT, SwingX, JGoodies, JavaFX, Apache Pivot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358775/java-gui-frameworks-what-to-choose-swing-swt-awt-swingx-jgoodies-javafx)

Answer (score 1):

You really just need a JFrame and a JPanel. The JFrame is the physical window that the gui lives in, while the JPanel is the content manager. You place JComponents (e.g. JLabel, JComboBox) into the JPanel.

Java Api: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

Examples of using each component: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you may try using [JavaFX 2.1](http://fxexperience.com/2012/04/announcing-javafx-2-1/) to develop your GUI in java. It has [Scene builder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html) tool to design your application, built-in support css-like [skin](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/css_tutorial/jfxpub-css_tutorial.htm).

Check the concurrency in Javafx 2.1 [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm).