# Framework for MVC in desktop (non-web) application

Tags: java, model-view-controller, frameworks, desktop-application

I would like to know are there any Java (MVC) framework for non-web application (desktop application)?
I have searched for a while, but the answers are all about Java web-application framework like Struts, Spring & Hibernate.

I used to develop PHP web application (using CodeIgniter framework), so I don't have much understanding about the Java environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java Swing components are already the "V" and "C" of the MVC approach. You have to add the models part. In fifteen years of Java I have never found any tools that are better than knowing the Swing components back-to-front. The Swing tutorials from Oracle are the best free way to start.

[Griffon](http://griffon.codehaus.org/) is a nice framework that has an MVC structure and is made to develop desktop applications.

Apache Pivot http://pivot.apache.org

Also please take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358775/java-gui-frameworks-what-to-choose-swing-swt-awt-swingx-jgoodies-javafx)

Comment: Hadoop? I've heard the name many times but never in relation to GUIs.

Answer (score 0):

Swing is the standard but if you are looking for alternatives I would recommend [Qt-jambi](http://qt-jambi.org/). I used it because I wanted to experiment a bit, it does a pretty good job. Also, it is now managed by the community.