# org.eclipse.swt.widgets vs. javax.swing.table: Why redefine it?

Tags: java, swing, widget, swt

I'm creating a table now using the `Table` type defined in `org.eclipse.swt.widgets`. Eclipse however is letting me know that there is also a `Table` I can use in `javax.swing.table`.

Upon investigation, the two `Table`s are accomplishing the same thing. Why then do we have two? What does one accomplish that the other doesn't?

Comment: SWT (IBM), Swing (former Sun Ms) are different GUI toolkits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on which framework you want to use. AWT/Swing and SWT are the two main frameworks for developing desktop apps in Java.

There is a good question about which one to choose [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358775/java-gui-frameworks-what-to-choose-swing-swt-awt-swingx-jgoodies-javafx).

So the answer seems to be: You will have to choose one of them (Swing or SWT), since you really don't want to mix them unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Should my choice have anything to do with Eclipse Plugins? For example, if I'm building a plugin, should I avoid Swing?

Comment: @Imray In general, you should avoid mixing these two technologies if possible. Eclipse is written using SWT, so are the Eclipse plugins. Consequently, this rules out Swing. You *can* use Swing if you really have to (as illustrated [here](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Swing-SWT-Integration/index.html)).