# Simplistic Java UI

Tags: java, user-interface, window, frame

I've programmed in Java before but only in creating plugins for game servers and stuff like that, so I don't really know the first thing about creating user interfaces. Here is something I'm going to try and recreate for education purposes: http://puu.sh/6kWgA.png

Can someone explain to me how basically ui's work and how can I proceed to achieving this goal. I've tried reading a few of the documentation pages but they're just no good for me, if someone could send me different written tutorials or videos which explain how I can create windows without the frame I would most appreciate it!

I need to know how to add things like drop-down menus, buttons, labels, tool-tips etc...

Thank you!

Comment: It's nice to see you are starting with something simple :/

Comment: Work through [Java `Swing` tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/start/index.html) first.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a matter covered by [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/), a comprehensive tutorial.

Comment: If you want an alternative to Swing you can also try [JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/).

Comment: *"create windows without the frame"*  The same way you can create a chicken without the egg.  It seems that you might want an undecorated frame (`JFrame`) or a `JWindow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually GUIs are done with the [Java Swing API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_(Java)).
A good starting point is this tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/.

Of course there are many other GUI frameworks available. For a good overview see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358775/java-gui-frameworks-what-to-choose-swing-swt-awt-swingx-jgoodies-javafx).