# Merging two images without using AWT

Tags: java, awt

I'm in a situation where I'm not allowed to use AWT libraries on a server but need to merge two images. I know only of one method in Java which is using `java.awt.Graphics.drawImage` and `java.awt.image.BufferedImage`.

Is it possible to merge two images not using AWT?

AWT-based example code:

```
try {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("a.png"));
    BufferedImage overlay = ImageIO.read(new File("b.png"));

    int width = Math.max(image.getWidth(), overlay.getWidth());
    int height = Math.max(image.getHeight(), overlay.getHeight());

    BufferedImage combination = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics g = combination.getGraphics();

    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    g.drawImage(overlay, 0, 0, null);

    ImageIO.write(combination, "png", new File("c.png"));
}
catch (IOException ioe) {
}
```

Comment: How do you mean? [Compositing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compositing)?

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want to run java headless? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html

Comment: Added source code. Unfortunately, I'm very explicitly not allowed to use AWT.

Comment: *"I'm very explicitly not allowed to use AWT."*  Very explicitly ***why?***  If you don't know, find out!  This answer cannot be adequately answered without understanding the 'why?'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered [ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/index.html)?

It is an open source, pure Java image processing library.

Comment: I'd bet that most image APIs in existence would use some of the AWT API, which means they would not work in a headless server (where anything AWT is ruled out).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but why?

Read: [Java GUI frameworks. What to choose? Swing, SWT, AWT, SwingX, JGoodies, JavaFX, Apache Pivot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358775/java-gui-frameworks-what-to-choose-swing-swt-awt-swingx-jgoodies-javafx?rq=1) here you will be able to find many others GUI frameworks which could be useful for you.

Comment: *"..many others GUI frameworks.."*  Not one of which will work on a headless server.  That is (99.3% sure) why the OP 'cannot use AWT' - though a better spec. from them would certainly help.

Comment: You are probably right. I haven't ever used none of them in headless server, but he just sayd that he can't use AWT. Reading Sounds unexpected, but actually you can perform different operations in this mode, even with graphic data. from java documentation. I suppose (hope) that it is possible with another GUI framework. Tell me if I'm wrong ;)