# How to create a org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image from a external JAR

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, jt400

**Question:**

I would like to know how to create an **org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image** object from a .gif in an external .jar file.

**Back Ground:**

I am creating a TreeViewer based on [TreeViewerArticle](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-TreeViewer/TreeViewerArticle.htm), and would like to reference a picture in the [jt400.jar file](http://jt400.sourceforge.net/) for one of my tree elements.

**Code Snippet:**

```
class ViewLabelProvider extends LabelProvider {

   public Image getImage(Object obj) {

      <<<<NEED CODE to create org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image >>>>

   }
}
```

**Solution:**

```
InputStream stream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/com/ibm/as400/access/AS40016.gif");
ImageData id = new ImageData(stream);
Image image = new Image(null, id);
return image;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-
    `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("File dir"));`

if getResource doesnt work try this.

```
public BufferedImage loadImage(String fileName){

    BufferedImage buff = null;
    try {
        buff = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return buff;

}
```

**try something like:**

```
InputStream stream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/images/image.jpg");
```

In your JAR file, you might have a directory structure of:

```
jt400.jar
- com (class files in here)
- images
----image.gif
```

[try these methods](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0240.html)

Comment: This is dealing with AWT / Swing images, the question is asking about SWT Images which are not the same thing.

Comment: awt is general term and swt is the term given by eclipse to swing + awt.

Comment: Sorry but that is not so. SWT is a completely separate windowing system for Eclipse and does not use anything from Swing or AWT. AWT is not a general term it refers specifically to the java.awt.* classes

Comment: Thanks for guiding me to the Solution, refer to the "Solution Paragraph" for my implementation.

Comment: they are all used in graphic designing, i can happen that i am wrong check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358775/java-gui-frameworks-what-to-choose-swing-swt-awt-swingx-jgoodies-javafx

Comment: @greg-449 i am not saying that awt + swing = swt but the features are almost the same with some changes...as it was created by IBM