# Creating Client GUI Application for hadoop Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I am masters student in Computer Science and as a part of my research, I needed to create the Hive Client and GUI for that. I have wrote the java program for Hive Client and its working perfectly fine. I am running my Java Program on SSH Terminal and it's giving me the expected output too. Now, I need to create the GUI for that program but i am not sure which tools or technologies in cloudera or other platform can be used to create the GUI. Can somebody help me figure out what can be used on hadoop/cloudera in order to generate the GUI application ? Replies are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java GUI frameworks. What to choose? Swing, SWT, AWT, SwingX, JGoodies, JavaFX, Apache Pivot?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358775/java-gui-frameworks-what-to-choose-swing-swt-awt-swingx-jgoodies-javafx)

Comment: Cloudera/Hadoop have no part in this question. It doesn't matter if you have hive. You essentially just asked how to make a GUI...

Comment: If you want a GUI against Hadoop, that's all client side and would require a JDBC connection. Or you could try a web page interface... Really, the question is quite broad because the UI could be written in practically any  framework

Comment: I have setup the hadoop using cloudera. Uploading my network tracing data into Hive and writing queries to detect network attacks. I have developed several queries. I already wrote a Hive client which establish the connection to hive but i want to create the UI for that program so i am just wondering any tools available in Hue/Cloudera to generate the UI application. Does question make sense now ?

Comment: As I said, the specifics of the operations shouldn't matter. You just want a GUI to connect to Hive. Excel can do that... There are no tools within CDH to create your own custom UI *specifically designed* for your queries. Hue is a decent UI. Apache Zeppelin notebooks could be useful.