# What is the difference between the Java awt package, Javafx, and Java Swing

Tags: java, user-interface

I am trying to make a standalone graphical Java program that runs on the users desktop (pref. Windows). I did some research, and came across the `java.awt.*` package, javafx, and Java Swing.

Can someone tell me the differences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java awt is the first generation, Java Swing is the second generation and the JavaFx is the third generation UI-Toolkit for designing and implementing Graphical User Interfaces with Java.

If you want to learn more about these APIs and the other related APIs, you did not mention, please read [the discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358775/java-gui-frameworks-what-to-choose-swing-swt-awt-swingx-jgoodies-javafx) and there is also a video about the differences between these three APIs [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uxmhqv0in34).

Comment: Note that all of the answers on the linked question are pretty old. The newest update is from 2013. JavaFX has seen some changes in the meantime.

Comment: @ModusTollens It is not a reason to downvote the answer. Except for the JavaFX, the other two are already old technologies and the linked post explains them good. In addition to the first link to the SO, there is also a linked video, which is published in 2015 and ratet good by community.

Comment: I agree that the linked post is not a reason to downvote. Just wanted to point readers to the fact that it is outdated.

Comment: A reason for a downvote would be that this answer doesn't show the differences between the technologies. It links to another post (doing so indicates that the question should be closed as a duplicate, but I wouldn't do it in this case because the answers on the linked question are outdated. I voted to close as "too broad" because it doesn't show research effort.)

Comment: You are right. Actually, this kind of questions should not be answered because of the fact that 1. the question is very broad. 2. It is duplicate 3. There are thousands of sources on net. However, I still wanted to direct the OP. That is why, I answered :)